# SQL. Group by the same consecutive elements

Tags: sql, teradata

Given the table with series of events ordered by column1 ("time"):

```
column1 , event_type
0       , 1
2       , 1
3       , 1
8       , 2
11      , 2
15      , 1
28      , 1
33      , 1
34      , 3
41      , 3
44      , 3
50      , 3
51      , 1
60      , 1
```

How can I group by *consecutive* events of the same type?

```
event_type, begins_at, ends_at
1         , 0        , 3
2         , 8        , 11
1         , 15       , 33
3         , 34       , 50
1         , 51       , 60
```

I have an assumption this can be made with window function, but I have no idea how.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      SELECT event_type, MIN(column1) AS begins_at, MAX(column1) AS ends_at
      FROM (
        SELECT column1, event_type,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) -
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY column1) AS groupingId
        FROM table1
      )A
      GROUP BY A.groupingId, event_type
      ORDER BY 2, 1
```